# How to correctly do upsert in postgres 9.5

Tags: sql, postgresql, upsert, postgresql-9.5

correct syntax of upsert with postgresql 9.5, below query shows `column reference "gallery_id" is ambiguous` error , why?

```
var dbQuery = `INSERT INTO category_gallery (
  category_id, gallery_id, create_date, create_by_user_id
  ) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4)
  ON CONFLICT (category_id)
  DO UPDATE SET
  category_id = $1,
  last_modified_date = $3,
  last_modified_by_user_id = $4
  WHERE gallery_id = $2`;
```

I tried change `WHERE gallery_id = $2;` to  `WHERE category_gallery.gallery_id = $2;` then shows error `there is no unique or exclusion constraint matching the ON CONFLICT specification`, but **I don't want to set gallery_id or category_id as unique** becuase I want to sure both column are same then do update....

How to correctly do upsert in postgres 9.5?

if `ON CONFLICT` need unique column, should I use other method, how?

I want to sure multiple column both conflict then do update, what is correct usage

```
var dbQuery = `INSERT INTO category_gallery (
  category_id, gallery_id, create_date, create_by_user_id
  ) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4)
  ON CONFLICT (category_id, gallery_id)
  DO UPDATE SET
  category_id = $1,
  last_modified_date = $3,
  last_modified_by_user_id = $4
  WHERE gallery_id = $2`;


var dbQuery = `INSERT INTO category_gallery (
  category_id, gallery_id, create_date, create_by_user_id
  ) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4)
  ON CONFLICT (category_id AND gallery_id)
  DO UPDATE SET
  category_id = $1,
  last_modified_date = $3,
  last_modified_by_user_id = $4
  WHERE gallery_id = $2`;
```

table  (category_id , gallery_id not unique column)

```
category_id | gallery_id | create_date | create_by_user_id | last_modified_date | last_modified_by_user_id
1 | 1 | ...  
1 | 2 | ...
2 | 2 | ...
1 | 3 | ...
```

Answer (score 76, accepted):

The `ON CONFLICT` construct requires a `UNIQUE` constraint to work. From the documentation on [`INSERT .. ON CONFLICT` clause](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-insert.html#SQL-ON-CONFLICT):

> The optional `ON CONFLICT` clause specifies an alternative action to raising a **unique violation** or **exclusion constraint** violation error. For each individual row proposed for insertion, either the insertion proceeds, or, if an arbiter constraint or index specified by conflict_target is violated, the alternative conflict_action is taken. `ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING` simply avoids inserting a row as its alternative action. `ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE` updates the existing row that conflicts with the row proposed for insertion as its alternative action.

Now, the question is not very clear but you probably need a `UNIQUE` constraint on the 2 columns combined: `(category_id, gallery_id)`.

```
ALTER TABLE category_gallery
    ADD CONSTRAINT category_gallery_uq
    UNIQUE (category_id, gallery_id) ;
```

If the row to be inserted matches **both** values with a row already on the table, then instead of `INSERT`, do an `UPDATE`:

```
INSERT INTO category_gallery (
  category_id, gallery_id, create_date, create_by_user_id
  ) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4)
  ON CONFLICT (category_id, gallery_id)
  DO UPDATE SET
    last_modified_date = EXCLUDED.create_date,
    last_modified_by_user_id = EXCLUDED.create_by_user_id ;
```

You can use either the columns of the UNIQUE constraint:

```
  ON CONFLICT (category_id, gallery_id)
```

or the constraint name:

```
  ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT category_gallery_uq
```

Comment: thanks for reply , but I don't want category_id or gallery_id be unique column, mention in question.  I want sure if category_id and gallery_id both same then create new row, please see my update date example in question

Comment: yes if already exists `category_id=1 and gallery_id=3` then update, not insert.  I use your script, if I want to update `category_id = 2 where gallery_id = 3 `  not working. or should I add another update script ?

Comment: I also tried this  `INSERT INTO category_gallery (
                category_id, gallery_id, create_date, create_by_user_id
                ) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4)
                ON CONFLICT (category_id, gallery_id)
                DO UPDATE SET
                category_id = $1,
                last_modified_date = EXCLUDED.create_date,
                last_modified_by_user_id = EXCLUDED.create_by_user_id
                WHERE category_gallery.gallery_id = $2`

Comment: I don't follow what you mean with `update category_id = 2 where gallery_id = 3`. Do you want to insert/update a row with `category_id = 2 and gallery_id = 3`? I don't have a `WHERE` anywhere in my script.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ  I've solved the problem thanks to your answer, but my issues is that calling `ON CONFLICT CONSTRAINT category_gallery_uq` by constraint name is incorrect and will cause syntax error, please kindly consider updating your answer by changing it to `ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT category_gallery_uq` . Big thank

Comment: upvoted! any way to do on conflict do update all columns without having to mention each

Answer (score 11):

As a simplified alternative to [the currently accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36799500/3169029), the `UNIQUE` constraint can be anonymously added upon creation of the table:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name (
    id  TEXT PRIMARY KEY,
    col TEXT,
    UNIQUE (id, col)
);
```

Then, the upsert query becomes (similar to what was already answered):

```
INSERT INTO table_name (id, col) VALUES ($1, $2)
ON CONFLICT (id, col)
    DO UPDATE SET col = $2;
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not for the Postgres' version asked, but someone might find interesting to check the great [`MERGE` feature](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/sql-merge.html) available in **PostgreSQL V15** and newer.

```
MERGE INTO customer_account ca
USING (SELECT customer_id, transaction_value FROM recent_transactions) AS t
ON t.customer_id = ca.customer_id
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET balance = balance + transaction_value
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT (customer_id, balance)
  VALUES (t.customer_id, t.transaction_value);
```