# How to Create PostgreSQL UPSERT Function that Accessing CTE Table Inner IF Statement?

Tags: postgresql, function, upsert

I want to create upsert function that accessing CTE Table inner IF Clause, but i found Error :

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "ON"
>
> LINE 12:   SELECT id , 999 FROM list ON CONFLICT (id)
>                                        ^
>
> ********** Error **********
>
> ERROR: syntax error at or near "ON" SQL state: 42601 Character: 346

Data in `hasil_perhitungan` table:

```
----------
id + hasil
---+------
21 + 666
22 + 777
23 + 777
24 + 777
25 + 777
---+------
```

Data in `list_di` :

```
---
id 
---
19
20
21
---
```

I have to try this :

[postgres syntax error at or near "ON"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40327449/postgres-syntax-error-at-or-near-on)

and

[UPSERT Postgres 9.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37585675/upsert-postgres-9-5)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION coba(input_data integer)
  RETURNS void AS
  $BODY$
BEGIN
IF EXISTS (SELECT id, CASE WHEN id = input_data THEN 'OK' END FROM hasil_perhitungan)
    THEN 
    WITH result AS (
    SELECT id FROM hasil_perhitungan)
    , list AS (
    SELECT id FROM list_di)
    INSERT INTO hasil_perhitungan 
    SELECT id , 999 FROM list ON CONFLICT (id)
        UPDATE SET hasil = 888;
END IF;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I have expected when i execute the function with IF statement and integer parameter that exist that can accessing CTE table inner the IF Statement. so
When I run function with :

```
SELECT coba(25);
```

The Function will insert and update so i get :

```
Data in hasil_perhitungan table :

----------
id + hasil
---+------
19 + 999
20 + 999
21 + 888
22 + 777
23 + 777
24 + 777
25 + 777
---+------
```

Answer (score 0):

You have several issues with your code

- There's no need for with clauses to run an `INSERT ON CONFLICT`
- `DO` keyword is missing in your query
- You probably don't require that `IF EXISTS` condition because that would mean you will always want an update and not insert. Even if you need it, that's not the right way of writing an `EXISTS` check, It should be something like:

`IF EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM hasil_perhitungan WHERE id = input_data ) THEN`

Perhaps this simple function should be sufficient to fulfil your requirement.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION coba(input_data integer)
  RETURNS void AS
  $BODY$
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO hasil_perhitungan 
    SELECT id , 999 FROM list_di ON CONFLICT (id)
       DO UPDATE SET hasil = 888;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Here's a **[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=f263e3a2af23caa2490e9c813a55575b)** of the working code for the above

Comment: Oke Thanks before Mr. Nayak, 

But for my real case i need:

1. CTE (With clauses), cause i need to join some table and made it as CTE, and select the CTE then insert it to a table

2. I need IF Else statement cause befor it i need to filtering some data that i have to use IF Else

the function above it just like algorithm of my function in the simple way, i need to make upsert function that need access CTE inner IF ELSE clause statement..

Thanks a lot Mr. Nayak,

The Best Regards

Comment: I new in postgreSQL moreover in its function