# Postgres - upsert on passed parameter

Tags: sql, postgresql, upsert

In my project I am using `Postgres 12` and I want to use one sql query to **INSERT OR UPDATE**..

My syntax is not correct.

**UPDATE: Insert works but updating does not.**

> ERROR:  Invalid parameter number: :name"

```
 'INSERT INTO user (
         name, url
  ) VALUES (:name, :url)
    ON CONFLICT (id)
    WHERE id = :userId
    DO UPDATE SET
             name = :name,
             url = :url'
```

I am using this [EXAMPLE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36799104/how-to-correctly-do-upsert-in-postgres-9-5) to do *UPSERT* and I want to *UPDATE* if `userId` is passed and if not to *INSERT* new row.

Thanks

Comment: The syntax is `INSERT INTO Table(Columns, ...) VALUES ... ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE SET ...` as you can see in the linked question. No `SET` clauses in an `INSERT`.

Comment: Get rid of the `SET` and use `VALUES` instead, as the SQL Standard mandates. `INSERT INTO t (col) VALUES ('VAL') ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE ...`

Comment: The syntax you are using is not the syntax the linked questions shows you and is [not documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html) . Why do you think inventing your own syntax would work?

Comment: I am pretty new in writing postgres queries so I was just asking for a little help for starters.. Thanks @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: I have updated my post with preposed solutions still have an error. @JeroenMostert

Comment: Your statement now no longer uses `:name` at all. Presumably you intended `VALUES (:name, :url)`. Though it's not clear where `EXCLUDED.created_at` is supposed to be coming from either.

Comment: I updated the post. Is this the way to go? @JeroenMostert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
BEGIN;
CREATE TABLE users (
    user_id bigint PRIMARY KEY GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,
    name text,
    url text
);
INSERT INTO users (name, url)
    VALUES ('Hello', 'world');
COMMIT;
```

using psql: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html
set variable in psql: [How do you use script variables in psql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36959/how-do-you-use-script-variables-in-psql)
You can also set variable in an transaction.

```
BEGIN;
\set name 'hi'
\set url 'yech'
INSERT INTO users (user_id, name, url)
    VALUES (1, :'name', :'url')
ON CONFLICT (user_id)
    DO UPDATE SET
        name = EXCLUDED.name, url = EXCLUDED.url
    RETURNING
        *;
TABLE users;
COMMIT;
```