# AWS Glue - Insert Update rows from source to destination

Tags: postgresql, etl, google-cloud-dataflow, aws-glue, data-warehouse

Using PostgreSQL as Source & Target for DataWareHouse (DWH) on AWS

We need to do incremental Insert & Update on target table using AWS Glue.

We search around but didn't found good example of how flow needs to be created.

Once we get data in target table, we will then create Dimension & Facts table based on it.

It's very basic requirements, are we missing something important here?

Can somebody please help here?

Comment: We found when we have destination as RedShift, there is an option to do UPSERT but with postgresql, it is not

Answer (score 2):

Here's how you should approach the problem:

1. Do you need to use Spark or not? If not, it would be much more efficient to use Glue Python Shell jobs.
2. Can you easily identify increments in the source? If so, make sure you're pulling just that, and pushing it either to S3 (and consider using AWS Glue data catalog) or directly to a `staging` schema in your destination database.
3. Postgres support `UPSERT` [in a specific way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30118648/398670) also [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36799104/how-to-correctly-do-upsert-in-postgres-9-5) and [in the official documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html). AWS Redshift, while based on Postgres, does not support that approach - you would instead need to develop a stored procedure, where you run both operations separately - `UPDATE` matched columns based on ID, or `INSERT` new columns where the ID is not matched.
4. Once you've created the DB structures, make sure you run the procedure that transfers incremental data from staging to production - that can be done via Glue as well.

Please elaborate on your specific setup if you need further support or recommendations on the Python libraries to use with Glue.